# How can have many-to-many result as list in pure SQL query

Tags: android, sql, join, many-to-many

I have many-to-many relation on two entities: `Student` and `Teacher`. They common table is `course`. Every student can have a course with a teacher. This is table schemas I'm filling them with initial test values:

```
 //Fill student table
 db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO student_table (studentId ,name , age,cityId ) VALUES  (1,'Mahdi',39 ,3)".trimIndent())

 //Fill teacher table
 db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO teacher_table (teacherId, name , grade ) VALUES  (1,'Zahra',99 )".trimIndent())
 db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO teacher_table (teacherId, name , grade ) VALUES  (2,'Shaby',120 )".trimIndent())

 //Fill course
 db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO course_table (courseId , studentId,teacherId  ) VALUES  (1,1,1 )".trimIndent())
 db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO course_table (courseId , studentId,teacherId ) VALUES  (5,1,2 )".trimIndent())
...
```

I wan to have a result that show students that connected to teachers by courses like this:

```
data class StudentAndTeachers(
    val student: Student,
    val teachers: List<Teacher>
)
```

So I expected to see teacher 1, 2 in relation with student 1.

In sql I did a join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM student_table LEFT join course_table on  course_table.studentId = student_table.studentId LEFT JOIN teacher_table on course_table.teacherId = teacher_table.teacherId group by student_table.studentId
```

But result wont fill list of teachers and only contain one teacher per student like bellow, but in my table I should see two teachers ( teacher id 1,2 ) for student ( studentId = 1 )

[image]

So how I can make result of join create list of my all relation ?

```
User1 (listOf(teacher1, teacher2))
```

Comment: This is unintelligible. What is the question? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. [mre] please. PS It is not necessary to know constraints to query or update. PS When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) Otherwise give a clear description & example of how goal output is a function of input plus working relevant code & a description of being stuck. Not fragments of both.

Comment: @philipxy Updated, hope more clear now!

Comment: "Not fragments of both." Etc etc. Please act on the comment. PS Android room seems irrelevant, there seems no need to mention it. PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation or base tables in terms of its column values.

Comment: What is the purpose of `grpup by` in your query? Why did you place it here? What you expect to get as a result? What is your DBMS? Please, provide some sample data in text format and desired output for this data

Comment: That why I mentioned about Room, all in sqlite , without group by it will show all matched records of Join.

Comment: Show the DB schema (at least the tables involved). Include some data (rows) and the expected and actual results of your query. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @astentx without group by I will have duplicated records of one student. Here I will have two records of student1 one with teacher1 and other with teacher2.

Comment: Then you obviously need to `group by studentid, teacherid`. In other databases you will have an error message that says you have columns that are neither in `group by` nor aggregated by some aggregate function. But in SQLite it works diferently (for whatever reason).

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to imagine what the schema is. But it would appear that you do not have a many to many relationship as you would accomplish this with what is known by terms such as *mapping table*, *reference table*, *associative table* .... (all basically the same thing)

Such a table typically has two columns one that references/maps one of the tables (e.g. student) and the other column references/maps to the other table such as the course.

Anyway here is an example of what you appear to be trying to achieve. It has a table for Students, a table for Teachers and a table for Courses. The course table includes a column that references/maps the teacher (assuming one teacher per course). Lastly there is the mapping table that caters for the many-many relationship that allows a course to have many students and for a student to be in many courses.

The Entities are :-

**Teacher**

```
@Entity(tableName = "teacher_table")
data class Teacher(
    @PrimaryKey
    var teacherId: Long? = null,
    var teacherDetails: String
)
```

**Student**

```
@Entity(tableName = "student_table")
data class Student(
    @PrimaryKey
    var studentId: Long? = null,
    var studentDetails: String
)
```

**Course**

```
@Entity(tableName = "course_table",
    /* Foreign Keys optional but enforces referential integrity */
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Teacher::class,
            parentColumns = ["teacherId"],
            childColumns = ["teacherIdMap"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class Course(
    @PrimaryKey
    var courseId: Long? = null,
    var courseDetails: String,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    var teacherIdMap: Long /* if only one teacher for the course */
)
```

Last the mapping table Entity **StudentCourseMap**

```
@Entity(tableName = "student_course_map_table",
    primaryKeys = ["studentIdMap","courseIdMap"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = Student::class,
            parentColumns = ["studentId"],
            childColumns = ["studentIdMap"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey( entity = Course::class,
            parentColumns = ["courseId"],
            childColumns = ["courseIdMap"],
            onDelete =  ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class StudentCourseMap(
    var studentIdMap: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    var courseIdMap: Long
)
```

To support the above and get a Course, with the Teacher and with All the Students in the course there is a POJO class **CourseWithTeacherAndStudents**

```
data class CourseWithTeacherAndStudents(

    @Embedded
    var course: Course,
    @Embedded
    var teacher: Teacher,
    @Relation(
        entity = Student::class,
        parentColumn = "courseId",
        entityColumn = "studentId",
        associateBy = Junction(
            StudentCourseMap::class,
            parentColumn = "courseIdMap",
            entityColumn = "studentIdMap"
        )
    )
    var studentList: List<Student>
)
```

This is similar to the class in your question (but also includes the course details) and is along the lines of what you want to retrieve from the database.

```
data class CourseWithTeacherAndStudents(

    @Embedded
    var course: Course,
    @Embedded
    var teacher: Teacher,
    @Relation(
        entity = Student::class,
        parentColumn = "courseId",
        entityColumn = "studentId",
        associateBy = Junction(
            StudentCourseMap::class,
            parentColumn = "courseIdMap",
            entityColumn = "studentIdMap"
        )
    )
    var studentList: List<Student>
)
```

To utilise the above the **AllDAO** is an @Dao annotated abstract class (can be an interface but if you want to process data from your own JOINS and abstract class can have functions with bodies ).

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(teacher: Teacher): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(student: Student): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(course: Course): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(courseMap: StudentCourseMap): Long
    @Query("SELECT courseId FROM course_table WHERE coursedetails=:courseDetails ")
    abstract fun getCourseIdByCourseDetails(courseDetails: String): Long
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM course_table JOIN teacher_table ON course_table.teacherIdMap = teacher_table.teacherId")
    abstract fun getAllCoursesWithTeacherAndStudents(): List<CourseWithTeacherAndStudents>
    
}
```

Putting it all together with a working example

- with a pretty standard @Database annotated class *(in this case for brevity and convenience .allowMainThreadQueries has be used)*
  is the following in an Activity

:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAO
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAO()

        val teacherId01 = dao.insert(Teacher(teacherDetails = "teacher1"))
        val teacherId02 = dao.insert(Teacher(teacherDetails = "teacher2"))
        val teacherId03 = dao.insert(Teacher(teacherDetails = "teacher3"))
        val teacherId04 = dao.insert(Teacher(teacherDetails = "teacher4")) // not used
        val courseId001 = dao.insert(Course(courseDetails = "Course1", teacherIdMap = teacherId01))
        val courseId002 = dao.insert(Course(courseDetails = "Course2", teacherIdMap = teacherId01))
        val courseId003 = dao.insert(Course(courseDetails = "Course3", teacherIdMap = teacherId02))
        val courseId004 = dao.insert(Course(courseDetails = "Course4", teacherIdMap = teacherId03))
        dao.insert(Course(courseDetails = "Course5", teacherIdMap = dao.insert(Teacher(teacherDetails = "teacher5"))))
        val studentID01 = dao.insert(Student(studentDetails = "student1"))
        val studentID02 = dao.insert(Student(studentDetails = "student2"))
        val studentID03 = dao.insert(Student(studentDetails = "student3"))
        val studentID04 = dao.insert(Student(studentDetails = "student4"))
        val studentID05 = dao.insert(Student(studentDetails = "student5"))
        val studentID06 = dao.insert(Student(studentDetails = "student6"))
        val studentID07 = dao.insert(Student(studentDetails = "student7"))
        val studentID08 = dao.insert(Student(studentDetails = "student8"))

        dao.insert(StudentCourseMap(studentID01,courseId001))
        dao.insert(StudentCourseMap(studentID01,courseId003))
        dao.insert(StudentCourseMap(studentID01,dao.getCourseIdByCourseDetails("Course5")))

        dao.insert(StudentCourseMap(studentID02,courseId002))
        dao.insert(StudentCourseMap(studentID02,courseId004))

        dao.insert(StudentCourseMap(studentID03,courseId001))
        dao.insert(StudentCourseMap(studentID04,courseId002))
        dao.insert(StudentCourseMap(studentID05,courseId003))
        dao.insert(StudentCourseMap(studentID06,courseId004))
        dao.insert(StudentCourseMap(studentID07,dao.getCourseIdByCourseDetails("Course2")))
        dao.insert(StudentCourseMap(studentID08,dao.getCourseIdByCourseDetails("Course5")))

        for(cwtas: CourseWithTeacherAndStudents in dao.getAllCoursesWithTeacherAndStudents()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Course is ${cwtas.course.courseDetails}. Teacher is ${cwtas.teacher.teacherDetails}. There are ${cwtas.studentList.size} students. they are:-")
            for (s: Student in cwtas.studentList) {
                Log.d("DBINFO","\tStudent Details are ${s.studentDetails} id is ${s.studentId}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result output to the log when running the above (just once) is :-

```
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO: Course is Course1. Teacher is teacher1. There are 2 students. they are:-
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO:   Student Details are student1 id is 1
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO:   Student Details are student3 id is 3
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO: Course is Course2. Teacher is teacher1. There are 3 students. they are:-
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO:   Student Details are student2 id is 2
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO:   Student Details are student4 id is 4
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO:   Student Details are student7 id is 7
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO: Course is Course3. Teacher is teacher2. There are 2 students. they are:-
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO:   Student Details are student1 id is 1
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO:   Student Details are student5 id is 5
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO: Course is Course4. Teacher is teacher3. There are 2 students. they are:-
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO:   Student Details are student2 id is 2
2022-03-23 19:01:57.337 D/DBINFO:   Student Details are student6 id is 6
2022-03-23 19:01:57.338 D/DBINFO: Course is Course5. Teacher is teacher5. There are 2 students. they are:-
2022-03-23 19:01:57.338 D/DBINFO:   Student Details are student1 id is 1
2022-03-23 19:01:57.338 D/DBINFO:   Student Details are student8 id is 8
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at first I was added that I can achieve this by room relations but wanna do with pure SQL cause room generate code shows that it handle with some separated queries.. but I asked to remove Room part cause it's not related. So I know how to handle in Room with Relation annotations but wanna pure SQL if available